# rsnapshot push TO the server FROM the client

Tags: rsnapshot

I have found out that rsnapshot is great tool for backing up my stuffs for local file system. 
Now I need to do rsnapshot_push.conf file where I give params to rsync server.
What is the right way to do this? Can I use rsync to /rsnapshot-backups/localhost/ syncing it to rsync server.

Answer (score 11):

Rsnapshot is pull-based by design. The power of Rsnapshot lies in using hard links, and that only works for local file systems. (nfs could be used as it supports hard links, but not for instance sshfs).

In a push scenario, the best solution is to simply push to to a backup directory on the server using rsync, and then allow rsnapshot handle snapshotting from that directory, as it was designed to. Rsnapshot doesn't care if changes were introduced by an rsync or by saving a file.

In the rsnapshot FAQ there is a [fancy solution that triggers rsnapshot after the rsync](http://www.rsnapshot.org/faq.html), but that could be overkill. Just running rsnapshot from its recular cron jobs works just as well.

An alternative solution is [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/), however this does not present a nice directory view of each snapshot and requires running commands to restore files, which may complicate fast restoring.

Comment: this would double the amount of space needed

Comment: assuming only the receiver has a static IP, one option it to do a reverse ssh tunnel, then take the rsnapshot from the local port where the sender's ssh server is listening to. the sender would make 2 ssh commands, the first for the reverse tunnel, the 2nd for initiating the rsnapshot on the receiver. this could be wrapped in a cron-triggered script on the sender side

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a reverse ssh tunnel and then to a "remote" pull from the receiver's side:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
IVAL=${1:-hourly}
ssh -vNR 1998:localhost:22 example.com &
ssh example.com "rsnapshot -c pull-from-sender-rsnapshot.conf ${IVAL}"
```

where `pull-from-sender-rsnapshot.conf` might contain a line like:

```
backup localhost:1998/etc/  desktop-1
```

This could be invoked by cron on the sender's side, triggering the remote rsnapshot locally.

Comment: Getting *Source directory "localhost:1998/etc/" doesn't exist, rsnapshot can not continue*

Answer (score 3):

I developed [rsnappush](https://osdn.net/users/ftobin/pf/rsnappush/) specifically to solve same problem you're encountering, and actually came across your post because I was looking for a pre-built solution (that didn't exist yet).

### SYNOPSIS

`rsnappush [-h] [-r RSYNC_OPT] [-q] SOURCE_PATH [ACCOUNT:]DEST_PATH`

### DESCRIPTION

**rsnappush** is a wrapper around rsync(1) to assist in file-level
incremental snapshots that are pushed to a destination.
Unchanged files are hard-linked.  Files are plainly laid
out in a directory for each snapshot: *DEST_PATH*/*backup-YYYYmmdd-HHMM*/
for easy access and restoration.

*SOURCE_PATH* is any local path.

*DEST_PATH* is a path, local or remote.  If remote, *ACCOUNT* specifies
an ssh(1)-compatible account description, such as *USER*@*HOST*.

Additionally, under *DEST_PATH* there is a *permissions*/ directory
created that has compressed output from getfacl(1).  setfacl(1) can be used
to restore permissions from this file once it is uncompressed.

### EXAMPLE

```
rsnappush --rsync-opt=--partial-dir=/home/user2/rsync-partial \
          /home/user user2@remotehost:backups/
```